# Find the density of sum of uniform random variable bounded by a triangle

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

We have n independent pairs $(X_i,Y_i)$, which are uniformly distributed over the triangle bounded by $$X_i+Y_i<\lambda$$ $$Y_i-X_i<\lambda$$ $$Y_i>0$$

Find the density of $A=|X_1|+|X_2|+Y_1+Y_2$

**My attempt:**

First, we find the density of $B=|X_1|+Y_1$, which is $$f_B(b)=\frac{2b}{\lambda^2}$$
Similarly, due to the independence of the pair, we have the density of $C=|X_2|+Y_2$ is $$f_C(c)=\frac{2c}{\lambda^2}$$, and their joint density $$f_{B,C}(b,c)=\frac{4bc}{\lambda^4}$$
Now, the density of A is: $$f_A(a)=\int_0^\lambda \frac{4(a-c)b}{\lambda^4}db=\frac{4}{\lambda^4}\left[\frac{1}{2}a\lambda^2-\frac{1}{3}\lambda^3\right]=\frac{2a}{\lambda^2}-\frac{4}{3\lambda}$$

**My question:**

I checked if it is a density function, but it does not equal $1$ when integrated. Hence, I don't know where I made the mistake. I hope someone can point it out or suggest another way to solve this problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have obviously misprinted and the integrated expression should be $\frac{4(a-\color{red}{b})b}{\lambda^4}$.

The main issue is however the limits of integration. Obviously the following inequalities have to be satisfied:
$$
0\le b\le\lambda,\quad\text{and}\quad 0\le a-b\le\lambda.
$$
Therefore the correct expression is:
$$
f_A(a)=\int_{\max(0,a-\lambda)}^{\min(\lambda,a)}\frac{4(a-b)b}{\lambda^4}\;{\rm d}b=\frac4{\lambda^4}\times\begin{cases}
\displaystyle\int_0^a(a-b)b\;{\rm d}b,& 0\le a\le \lambda\\
\displaystyle\int_{a-\lambda}^\lambda(a-b)b\;{\rm d}b,& \lambda\le a\le 2\lambda\\
\end{cases}.
$$
You can check that
$$
\int_0^{2\lambda}f_A(a)\;{\rm d}a=1.
$$

Comment: thank you, it is very clear now.

Comment: @CynoBenette You are welcome.

Comment: Actually, I checked it again according to your suggestion, but it still does not integrate to 1. For example the first case after integrating I got 8/3 and in the second case after integrating I got 0. Is there something missing here?

Comment: nevermind, I got the missing part, it integrates to 1 now

Comment: I do not understand which "missing part" you mean. According to my calculation The function integrates to $\frac16$ on $[0,\lambda]$ and to $\frac56$ on $[\lambda,2\lambda]$. If you like I can add the details of the calculation.

Comment: oh, you don't have to add details. I got my missing part, not yours. your answer is correct.